# How to print values from bibtex entry fields?

Tags: biblatex

I have multiple website references on my document. I'm using bibtex with `@misc` to specify them.
I need to keep switching between referencing this sites in the normal way together with all the other references, or have them in footnotes. I want to make this switches as painless as possible and so my idea is to use a new command to cite a website, say `\wcite`. I would define it as:

```
\newcommand{\wcite}[1]{\cite{#1}} %normal cite  
\newcommand{\wcite}[1]{\footnote{\bibtitle{#1} - \bibhowpublished{#1}}} %footnote cite
```

Then I would comment the one I'm not using at the moment. This allows me to switch from citations to footnotes quickly, writing the website's data only once. I can also easily change the format of the footnote.

My obvious problem is that `\bibtitle` or `\bibhowpublished` do not exist. I couldn't find a way to get the string values from a bib entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BibLaTeX provides the entry type `@online` with `url` as one of the field. Thus you might want to consider to use this entry type to store website.

One can define new types of citations using `\DeclareCiteCommand`, thus the way to define the command to print the title and the url in footnotes could be something like:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\wcite}
    [\mkbibfootnote]
    {}
    {\printfield{title}--\printfield{url}}
    {\addcomma\addspace}
    {}
```

The first argument is the name of  the command (`\wcite`); the second argument, an optional one, is to wrap the command (in this cases in a footnote, using the facility provided by BibLaTeX; the third argument is for a pre code; the fourth is for the content of the citation: the value of a field can be printed using `\printfield{field name}`; the fifth argument is for the code to be printed  between multiple citations; finally the last argument is for the postcode.

To use the `howpublished` field replace `\printfield{url}` with `\printfield{howpublished}`

**EDIT**

It is possible to prevent the inclusion of web-site (`@misc`) in the bibliography by using the `defenumbers` option (the document must be compiled an even number of times after the bibliography has been generated)

```
\usepackage[defernumbers]{biblatex}

\printbibliography[nottype=misc]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can use BibLaTeX. I must use Springer's splncs for bibliography style, and from what I know, biblatex does not use the .bst

Comment: @brita_ What you want cannot be done with standard `bst` styles and  BibTeX.  I'm working on a biblatex style emulating Springer splncs, it is in an embryonic stage, and I don't know if biblatex is compatible with Springer production system for LNCS.  It is available at https://github.com/gvdgdo/biblatex-lncs

Comment: It took me some time, but I now have everything working. Your solution works perfectly for me, though, as you said, your emulation of Springer's splncs style is still embryonic. For instance, '@online' or '@misc' entries are not being correctly printed. Can you point me out to a place where I can get help with using your style?

Comment: @brita_ I hope to be able to spend a couple of hours this weekend to progress with the style.

Comment: I have just noticed that by using this solution with `\DeclareCiteCommand` my footnotes are still counted as references and I didn't want that. I can print only non-websites in the bibliography with option nottype=misc or online, but the entries are still numbered which leaves my bibliography with gaps.